# SCCM 2012 - Multi-domain?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, sccm-2012

I was wondering if it's possible to use SCCM 2012 in a multidomain environment? 
We have several domains each in their own forests but with the possibility of network connectivity.

Would it be sufficient to set serveral Active-Directory Forests, with their own set of credentials + their own Boundaries and Boundary Groups?

How is this done best-practice-wise?

The idea is to use SCCM2012 as a tool for keeping servers up to date via WSUS. 
Would that be doable? Are there issues we could run in to by using this?

Answer (score -1):

refer below link would be help for you .

http://blogs.technet.com/b/configmgrteam/archive/2011/03/30/active-directory-forest-discovery-and-publishing-in-configuration-manager-2012-beta-2.aspx

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers